# postgres daily data group by per hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have tables like this

```
services
    id | service_name
    1  | service1
    2  | service2
    3  | service3
```

and the services has many tokens

```
token
    id     | generated_time          | token_name | service_id
    461087 | 2016-10-21 09:02:53.951 |  G1        | 1
    461088 | 2016-10-21 09:31:13.469 |  C1        | 1
    461089 | 2016-10-21 09:31:15.711 |  C2        | 2
    461090 | 2016-10-21 10:37:17.73  |  C3        | 2
    461091 | 2016-10-21 10:02:53.951 |  G2        | 1
    461092 | 2016-10-21 10:15:13.469 |  C4        | 1
    461093 | 2016-10-21 11:22:15.611 |  C5        | 3
    461094 | 2016-10-21 11:31:14.743 |  C6        | 3
```

and token has one to one relation with token_queue

```
token_queue
    serving_end_time        |  serving_start_time      | token_id
    2016-10-21 09:04:45.681 |  2016-10-21 09:03:49.05  | 461087 
    2016-10-21 09:33:49.035 |  2016-10-21 09:32:07.996 | 461088 
    2016-10-21 09:34:42.431 |  2016-10-21 09:32:27.134 | 461089 
    2016-10-21 10:39:57.775 |  2016-10-21 10:38:37.428 | 461090
    2016-10-21 10:04:49.715 |  2016-10-21 10:03:09.972 | 461091
    2016-10-21 10:17:28.268 |  2016-10-21 10:16:06.946 | 461092
    2016-10-21 11:23:36.036 |  2016-10-21 11:22:30.233 | 461093
    2016-10-21 11:32:32.876 |  2016-10-21 11:31:27.044 | 461094
```

now i want to display min/max time taken of all the services of 24 hours in per hour basis of token table's **generated_time**. min/max here is calculated by

```
MIN(token_queue.serving_end_time - token_queue.serving_start_time)
MAX(token_queue.serving_end_time - token_queue.serving_start_time)
```

for example

```
    hour -  2016-10-21 09:00:00
       service1
         min - 00:01:06
         max - 00:05:00
       service2
          min - 00:01:40
          max - 00:03:00
      service3
          min - 00:01:02
          max - 00:03:12

    hour -  2016-10-21 10:00:00
       service1
         min - 00:01:20
         max - 00:02:50
       service2
          min - 00:01:30
          max - 00:03:45
      service3
          min - 00:02:02
          max - 00:05:12
```

I tried this

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', t.generated_time) AS hour,
       t.service_id AS service,
       min(tq.serving_end_time - tq.serving_start_time) AS min,
       max(tq.serving_end_time - tq.serving_start_time) AS max
FROM token t
     JOIN token_queue tq
        ON t.id = tq.token_id
GROUP BY service,hour;
```

but from this i can only print like this

```
hour - 2016-10-21 09:00:00
  service1
     min - 00:01:06
     max - 00:05:00
hour - 2016-10-21 09:00:00
  service2
     min - 00:01:40
     max - 00:03:00
hour - 2016-10-21 10:00:00
  service1
     min - 00:01:06
     max - 00:05:00
hour - 2016-10-21 10:00:00
  service2
     min - 00:01:30
     max - 00:03:45
```

thank you for any help and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

well i managed it by grouping the array result

```
foreach($min_max_avg as $mma){
    $hour = $mma->hour;
        if (isset($result[$hour])) {
                $result[$hour][] = $mma;
        } else {
                 $result[$hour] = array($mma);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there and don't need to rearrange your result.

I suggest adding the service_name for easier printing, and order the query result by hour first and then service_name ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e021a/4/0))

```
select date_trunc('hour', t.generated_time) as hour,
       s.service_name as service,
       min(tq.serving_end_time - tq.serving_start_time) as min,
       max(tq.serving_end_time - tq.serving_start_time) as max
from token t
join token_queue tq on t.id = tq.token_id
join services s on s.id = t.service_id
group by service, hour
order by hour, service
```

Now you can print the result as you go, you only need to remember the current hour and start a new section, when it changes

```
$current_hour = 0;
foreach ($min_max_avg as $mma) {
    if ($mma->hour != $current_hour) {
        echo "hour - $mma->hour\n";
        $current_hour = $mma->hour;
    }

    echo "    $mma->service\n";
    echo "        min - $mma->min\n";
    echo "        max - $mma->max\n";
}
```